# Spark: Explicit caching can interfere with Catalyst optimizer's ability to optimize some queries?

Tags: performance, apache-spark, dataset, catalyst

I'm studying to take the data bricks to spark certification exam, and their practice exam ( please see > https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/793177bc53e528530b06c78a4fa0e086/0/6221173/100020/latest.html )  requires us to accept this statement as true fact:

> "Explicit caching can decrease application performance by interfering
>   with the Catalyst optimizer's ability to optimize some queries"

I got this question wrong even though I have read up a lot on the catalyst and have a pretty good grasp of the details. So I wanted to shore up my knowledge of this topic and go to the source which explains the how's and why's behind this assertion.

Can anyone provide guidance about this?  Specifically, why is this so? and how do we ensure that when we cache our datasets we are not actually getting in the way of the optimizer and making things worse?   /Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### How and why can a cache decrease the performances ?

Let's use a simple example to demonstrate that :

```
// Some data
val df = spark.range(100)

df.join(df, Seq("id")).filter('id <20).explain(true)
```

Here, the catalyst plan will optimize this join by doing a filter on each dataframe before joining, to reduce the amount of data that will get shuffled.

```
== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Project [id#0L]
+- Join Inner, (id#0L = id#69L)
   :- Filter (id#0L < 20)
   :  +- Range (0, 100, step=1, splits=Some(4))
   +- Filter (id#69L < 20)
      +- Range (0, 100, step=1, splits=Some(4))
```

If we cache the query after the join, the query won't be as optimized, as we can see here :

```
df.join(df, Seq("id")).cache.filter('id <20).explain(true)

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Filter (id#0L < 20)
+- InMemoryRelation [id#0L], true, 10000, StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
      +- *Project [id#0L]
         +- *BroadcastHashJoin [id#0L], [id#74L], Inner, BuildRight
            :- *Range (0, 100, step=1, splits=4)
            +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false]))
               +- *Range (0, 100, step=1, splits=4)
```

The filter is done at the very end ...

Why so ? Because a `cache` writes on the disk the dataframe. So every consequent queries will use this cached / written on disk DataFrame, and so it will optimize only the part of the query AFTER the cache. We can check that with the same example !

```
df.join(df, Seq("id")).cache.join(df, Seq("id")).filter('id <20).explain(true)

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Project [id#0L]
+- Join Inner, (id#0L = id#92L)
   :- Filter (id#0L < 20)
   :  +- InMemoryRelation [id#0L], true, 10000, StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
   :        +- *Project [id#0L]
   :           +- *BroadcastHashJoin [id#0L], [id#74L], Inner, BuildRight
   :              :- *Range (0, 100, step=1, splits=4)
   :              +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false]))
   :                 +- *Range (0, 100, step=1, splits=4)
   +- Filter (id#92L < 20)
      +- Range (0, 100, step=1, splits=Some(4))
```

The filter is done before the second join, but after the first one because it is cached.

#### How to avoid ?

By knowing what you do ! You can simply compares catalyst plans  and see what optimizations Spark is missing.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer and example.  Just to pick a nit, I noticed that in your  cache'd version of the dataframe definition you did the join twice, whereas in the original you had only one join:   df.join(df, Seq("id")).filter('id <20).explain(true) - Even with this change your observation is true..   The filter is done at the end.

Comment: One other observation on the answer. You said that caching is a way to force the query to be executed.. but my understanding is that is not correct. You have to execute an action on the dataset/frame to force execution.  This is mentioned in mr. jackek laskowski's book here-> https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-caching-and-persistence.html      --  Minor point though... thnx again for the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback, concerning the joins, I have done two joins on purpose to show that the cached one, does not get optimized, and the second one does. Concerning the cache, thank you very much, I really did not know it was not an action which executes the query plan (Jacek also write this is an action in the same link, but he is telling everywhere else it is not, so it is probably not !) Thank you very much for the feedback

Comment: So, I miss . df.join(df, Seq("id")).filter('id <20).cache.explain(true). Not sure I follow this

Comment: @thebluephantom, not sure to get what your question is ? With your query, I expect the push down predicate to optimize your filter, if it is the question :)

Comment: I would expect the same as the 1st example but caching latterly. But did not get that.

Comment: What do you expect by `caching latterly` ? I do not expect the cache to be present in the physical plans. However you can check them out in the Spark UI !

Comment: i see deserialized. i will post a question, surprused u cannot answer as it is a good answer. anyway

Comment: Sorry for that ! With more details on a question it might be easier for me to see your point :)

Comment: ok i am going to post a question on this question later i will loop u in