# pyspark data pipeline use intermediary results

Tags: pyspark

In pyspark, I'd doing successive operations on dataframes and like to get outputs from intermediate results. It always takes the same time though, I'm wondering if it ever caches anything? Asked differently, what's best practice for using intermediary results? In [dask you can do](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/caching.html#two-simple-solutions) `dd.compute(df.amount.max(), df.amount.min())` which will figure out what needs to cached and computed. Is there an equivalent in pyspark?

In the example below, when it gets to `print()` will it execute 3x?

```
df_purchase = spark.read.parquet("s3a:/example/location")[['col1','col2']]
df_orders = df_purchase.groupby(['col1']).agg(pyspark.sql.functions.first("col2")).withColumnRenamed("first(col2, false)", "col2")
df_orders_clean = df_orders.dropna(subset=['col2'])

print(df_purchase.count(), df_orders.count(), df_orders_clean.count())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, each time you do an action on a dag. It executes and optimizes the full query.

By default, Spark caches nothing.

Be careful when caching, a cache can interfer in a negative way : [Spark: Explicit caching can interfere with Catalyst optimizer's ability to optimize some queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57369904/spark-explicit-caching-can-interfere-with-catalyst-optimizers-ability-to-optim/57371419#57371419)

Comment: Roger thanks! Seems if I add `df_orders.perist(); df_orders_clean.persist()` it runs much faster on the first run and even faster in successive runs.

Comment: @citynorman, my pleasure ! Be careful when caching, I updated my answer :)