# Spark SQL joining multiple tables design

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am developing a Spark SQL analytics solutions using set of tables. Suppose there are 5 tables which i need to building my solution and finally i am creating one output table.
Here is my flow

```
dataframe1 = table1 join table2
dataframe2 = dataframe1 join table3
dataframe3 = datamframe2 + filter + agg
dataframe4 = dataframe3 join table4 join table 5 
// finally 
dataframe4.saveAsTable
```

When I save final dataframe that's when all the above dataframe is evaluated.
Is my approach is good? or
Do i need to cache/persist intermediate dataframes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very generic question and it is hard to provide a definitive answer.

Depending on the size of tables you would want to do broadcast hint for any of tables that are relatively small.
You can do this via

```
table_i.join(broadcast(table_j), ....)
```

This behaviour depends on the value in:
Now broadcast hint will be honoured only if Spark is able to evaluate the value of the table so you might need to `cache()`.
Another option is via Spark checkpoints that can help to truncate local plan for optimisation (also this allows you to resume jobs from checkpoint location, it is similar to writing to HDFS but with some overhead).

In case of broadcasting few houndres of Mb tables, you might need to increase your kryo buffer:

```
    --conf spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=1g
```

It also depends which join types you will use.
You would probably want to do filter and aggregagtion as early as possible since it will reduce the join surface.

There are many other considerations to be consider in order to properly optimise this. In case of power law distribution of join keys in any of the joins you would need to do salting and explode smaller table.

Comment: Thanks @milos. My question is not about optimization rather simple design. Do we persist/cache intermediate dataframe or execute all queries at the final step when action is invoked.

Comment: you only cache/persist/checkpoint things you need to reuse, if the dataframe is only used once there is not need to cache it since there wont be any benefits from this action.

Answer (score 0):

- In your case, in principle, there is not really a cache or persist required Why?

  - As there are no reuse paths evident (for other Actions or other Transformations within the same Action), it is all sequential.
  - Also, lazy evaluation and Catalyst.
  - Try the .explain and see how Spark will process.
- However, due to memory eviction possibilities on the Cluster, there may be the need to re-compute on a Worker. There are various settings that you could apply via .cache and .persist, but Spark handles memory and disk spills without explicit .cache or .persist. See https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-difference-between-cache-and-persist/
- Also, using .cache can affect performance. So use .explain. See here an excellent posting: [Spark: Explicit caching can interfere with Catalyst optimizer's ability to optimize some queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57369904/spark-explicit-caching-can-interfere-with-catalyst-optimizers-ability-to-optim)

So, each case is different but yours seems Ok to answer as I have. In summary: An RDD or DF that is not cached, nor check-pointed, is re-evaluated again each time an Action is invoked on that RDD or DF or if re-accessed within the current Action and no skipped stage situation applies. In your case no issue. Doing otherwise would slow your App down in fact.