# Spark caching effect on Optimized Logical Plan

Tags: apache-spark, caching

I was looking at this question and excellent answer [Spark: Explicit caching can interfere with Catalyst optimizer's ability to optimize some queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57369904/spark-explicit-caching-can-interfere-with-catalyst-optimizers-ability-to-optim)

Gist is that this:

```
val df = spark.range(100)
df.join(df, Seq("id")).filter('id <20).explain(true)
```

generates a sufficiently robust plan for a system not using indexes by applying filtering first:

```
== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Project [id#16L]
+- Join Inner, (id#16L = id#18L)
   :- Filter (id#16L < 20)
   :  +- Range (0, 100, step=1, splits=Some(8))
   +- Filter (id#18L < 20)
      +- Range (0, 100, step=1, splits=Some(8))
```

The example then shows that:

```
df.join(df, Seq("id")).cache.filter('id <20).explain(true)
```

generates this plan:

```
== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Filter (id#16L < 20)
+- InMemoryRelation [id#16L], StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
      +- *(2) Project [id#16L]
         +- *(2) BroadcastHashJoin [id#16L], [id#21L], Inner, BuildRight
            :- *(2) Range (0, 100, step=1, splits=8)
            +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false])), [id=#112]
               +- *(1) Range (0, 100, step=1, splits=8)
```

Then what about this?

```
df.join(df, Seq("id")).filter('id <20).cache.explain(true)
```

that generates:

```
== Optimized Logical Plan ==
InMemoryRelation [id#16L], StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
   +- *(1) Filter (id#16L < 20)
      +- *(1) InMemoryTableScan [id#16L], [(id#16L < 20)]
            +- InMemoryRelation [id#16L], StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
                  +- *(2) Project [id#16L]
                     +- *(2) BroadcastHashJoin [id#16L], [id#21L], Inner, BuildRight
                        :- *(2) Range (0, 100, step=1, splits=8)
                        +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false])), [id=#112]
                           +- *(1) Range (0, 100, step=1, splits=8)
```

Looking for a clarification.

- I would have thought that the 1st Opt Log Pl would be gotten with caching as last aspect. Must be simple I suspect. Is it the same thing? I think not.

Comment: Hello there ! Which version of Spark are you using ? I have a different OLP on my local spark-shell with Spark `2.4.4`

Comment: 245 on databricks

Comment: will try on 3 later @BlueSheepToken

Comment: I answered it, hope this all makes sense ! On Spark3, this is an interesting experiment (done it), but it will add noise to understand the push down predicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I do think you run into a bug in the experiment.

If you run the following in a new spark-shell:

```
val df = spark.range(100)
df.join(df, Seq("id")).filter('id <20).cache.explain(true)
```

You will have the following Optimized Logical Plan:

```
== Optimized Logical Plan ==
InMemoryRelation [id#0L], StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
   +- *(2) Project [id#0L]
      +- *(2) BroadcastHashJoin [id#0L], [id#2L], Inner, BuildRight
         :- *(2) Filter (id#0L < 20)
         :  +- *(2) Range (0, 100, step=1, splits=12)
         +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false]))
            +- *(1) Filter (id#2L < 20)
               +- *(1) Range (0, 100, step=1, splits=12)
```

with the pushdown predicate correctly pushing filter.

However, in a new spark-shell, if you run:

```
val df = spark.range(100)
df.join(df, Seq("id")).cache.filter('id <20).explain(true)
df.join(df, Seq("id")).filter('id <20).cache.explain(true)
```

You will have the following Optimized Logical Plan:

```
== Optimized Logical Plan ==
InMemoryRelation [id#0L], StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
   +- *(1) Filter (id#0L < 20)
      +- *(1) InMemoryTableScan [id#0L], [(id#0L < 20)]
            +- InMemoryRelation [id#0L], StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
                  +- *(2) Project [id#0L]
                     +- *(2) BroadcastHashJoin [id#0L], [id#2L], Inner, BuildRight
                        :- *(2) Range (0, 100, step=1, splits=12)
                        +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false]))
                           +- *(1) Range (0, 100, step=1, splits=12)
```

with a non optimized plan.

### Why ?

This is because we already cached the DAG: `df.join(df, Seq("id"))`.

So even if we write it again with a filter and a cache after the filter, the Spark-Engine will see the `join` DAG and run it from here, so adding a filter afterwise. For the Spark engine, it is faster to use a cached Dataframe than recomputing the whole DAG.

### How to solve ?

One can simply `unpersist` the dag: `df.join(df, Seq("id")).unpersist()` and then `df.join(df, Seq("id")).filter('id <20).cache.explain(true)` gives the right OLP

Comment: To me it looks like a bug. Is that your conclusion?

Comment: I restarted the cluster but i will recheck. Interesting point that I had considered but did not address. Will verify later tonight.

Comment: Not really a bug as we cached the DAG. It is supposed to be retrieved easier then recomputing the whole DAG (here it is a simple dag, but it could be way more complex

Comment: @thebluephantom I think restarting the session should be enough (or unpersist the dataframe), restarting the cluster might be overkill !

Comment: Must be it. Cheers. I restarted the cluster but must have erred.

Comment: You should try to simply unpersist: `df.join(df, Seq("id")).unpersist()` and then `df.join(df, Seq("id")).filter('id <20).cache.explain(true)`

Comment: Plus one to unpersisting whats previously cached. Worth the answer itself being updated IMO.

Comment: I know that but u get issues on Databricks so as it happened I restarted

Comment: I think i have another point to make but am in transit  but good stuff

Comment: Post mortem: So, I may have erred in the test setup, but I noted the 2 caching aspects on the .explain but failed to make the connection on interpreting, that is to say I thought may be a bug as it read back from source. It is showing that I felt. Now I confirm some of the thoughts I had about the reading of the DAG and the ,.explain.